# Jenkins multi branch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

I have branch called feature/xyz.
Now I have to name a file from filename.exe to filename_$BRANCH_NAME.exe

But problem here is as my branch name has fwd slash it is throwing an error.

So how can I name my file as filename_feature_xyz??

Answer (score 1):

Example of code below. Essentially you can just use the string replace function. But went a bit further to cater for an unknown filename conforming to the convention you laid out in the example.

```
#!groovy
// Setup vars to replicate your questions specs
env.BRANCH_NAME = "feature/xyz"
String file = 'filename.exe'

// Replace any forward slash with an underscore
String branchName = (env.BRANCH_NAME).replace('/', '_')

// Split apart your current filename
List fileParts = file.tokenize('.')

// Construct the original filename, catering for multiple period usecases
String originalFileName = fileParts[0..-2].join('.')

// Seperate the extension for use later
String originalExtension = fileParts[-1]

// Combine into the desired filename as per your requirements
String newFileName = "${originalFileName}_${branchName}.${originalExtension}"
```